# FFMPEG: when batch converting, how do you skip extension types?

Tags: ffmpeg, batch-processing

simple BASH script:

```
for i in *; do
  ffmpeg -i "$i" -vcodec copy -acodec aac "${i/%.*}_AAC.mp4"
  rm "$i"
done
```

i'd like to modify this so as to ignore `.srt` files, and any other extension other than the standard video ones.  if possible, i'd also like it to traverse subdirectories, but i think i can just `ls -R | <script>` and that should do it.  can i replace the '*' with a RegEx?  i'm posting from mobile, so i can't test any of this out until i tonight.

EDIT:  i am running this in BASH as a script.  i will be compiling ffmpeg with x265 encoding support later, so i expect i'll be re-running this script once i have that done.

Comment: Are you using a shell? Like bash for instance? And how would you set the boundary of "any other extension other than the standard video ones"? You need to define that. Also, assuming that you are able to set that boundary, not all types/codecs can be contained in mp4. So vcodec copy will not always work.

Comment: Also, `rm "$i"` is a bad idea until you play the encoded file and feel everything worked out to your satisfaction. :)

Comment: the `rm` will be replaced with an `mv` command.  managed to convince mgmt that data storage is cheaper than re-sourcing the video if something goes sideways down the line.  i'm sure as heck not going to watch several hundred dopey iPhone vids to QC!

Answer (score 1):

In bash 4 this will recurse subdirectories below current directory and work on 4 extensions- avi, mp4, mpg, mpeg. You can add more if you like.

```
shopt -s globstar nullglob dotglob
for file in ./**/*.{mpg,mpeg,mp4,avi}
do 
ffmpeg -i "$file" -c:a aac -b:a 128k -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p \
-crf 22 -refs 1 -bf 0 -coder 0 -g 25 -keyint_min 15 -movflags +faststart \
${file%.*}_converted.mp4
done
```

The added parameters are as a sample of what is possible to use. You can set your own -crf, threads etc.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Will modify accordingly.

Comment: As for `-refs 1 -bf 0 -coder 0 -g 25 -keyint_min 15` users may blindly copy and paste these options without modifying them to better suit their needs. The [x264 encoding presets](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264#Preset) (the `-preset` option) will deal with most of those options. Your options appear to be somewhat like `-preset ultrafast` which is the fastest, yet most inefficient preset.

Comment: I do usually mention that users may set their own parameters. Perhaps I should use some standard disclaimer instead of having to think up something new every time.